# How do I fix the warning in python: This code is unreachable

Tags: python

I am learning pygame and I am working on a collision here is the code:

```
    def collision(bullx, bully, enemyx, enemyy):
        distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyx - bullx, 2) + math.pow(enemyy - bully, 2))
        if distance < 40:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        if collision(bullx, bully, enemyx, enemyy):
            quit()
```

Those last two lines give me the warning: This code is unreachable

If anyone knows how to fix this please inform

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: why you used the ** ?

Comment: that was just to point out the lines which I had an issue in

Comment: What is the desired behavior of the code? When do you assume the last two lines are executed?

Comment: ok, so it was due to bad indentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you indentation is wrong and the last two lines are not part of the function collision.

```py
def collision(bullx, bully, enemyx, enemyy):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyx - bullx, 2) + math.pow(enemyy - bully, 2))
    if distance < 40:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if collision(bullx, bully, enemyx, enemyy):
    quit()
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help